# Is ChildProcess running or dead? - node.js

Tags: node.js, child-process

Is there any official (documented) way, given [`ChildProcess`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) instance how to find out whether the process is still alive or dead?

I don't want to listen to `exit` event, I only want to synchronously obtain info whether the process has already terminated.

So far I found undocumented:

```javascript
const isAlive = process.exitCode === null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by "dead" you mean that the process is no longer running, the "correct" method is to listen for the ChildProcess' `exit` event.

Other than than, it depends on the architecture on which you're running the process.

### On Linux

On Linuxes that support [procfs - the process pseudo-filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs), you can check the state of a process by checking for the existence of its `id` under the `/proc` directory.

Assuming your child process id is 1234, reading `/proc/1234/status`, you'll find quite a lot of information about the process including:

```
State:    R (running)
```

#### Example Code:

```
var fs=require('fs'),
    pid = 1234
    procInfo;

// possible values for State value in /proc/pid/status
// R running, 
// S is sleeping, 
// D is sleeping in an uninterruptible wait, 
// Z is zombie (not running but held by process owner)
// T is traced or stopped

try {
  procInfo=fs.readFileSync('/proc/'+pid+'/status').toString();
}
catch(e){
  console.error('process does not exist');
}

if(!procInfo.match(/State:\s+[RSDT]/)){
  console.error('process is not running');
}
```

### On OSX (or other Unix-like operating systems)

The only generic way to check process status would be to shell out to the [`ps` command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ps.1.html) to view the status of a single process or of the list of currently known processes.

However, this is not (and cannot be made) a synchronous process using Node versions less than and including v0.10.44 (which relies on events to handle all communications with external processes).

For versions of Node greater than v0.10.44, there are synchronous versions of the standard `child_process` functions that can be used.

#### Example Code

```
'use strict';

var util=require('util'),
    nodeVersion=parseFloat(process.version.replace(/^v|\.\d+$/g,'')), // version as Major.MinorPatch like: 0.1044 for v0.10.44
    pid=1234,
    txt='';


// expected output from ps:
//   PID   TT    STAT   TIME    COMMAND
//   1224  s000  S   0:00.08    child_process

// meaning of first letter in STAT column
// I IDLE
// R RUNNING
// S SLEEPING
// T STOPPED
// U WAIT
// Z DEAD

/**
 * Returns true if process id is currently running.
 *
 * @param {Number|String} pid - id of process
 * @param {String} str - output from `ps` command
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isProcessRunning=function(pid,str){
  if(!str.match(new RegExp('(^'+pid.toString()+'.+?$)','m'))){
    //throw new Error('process does not exist');
    return false;
  }
  var parts=RegExp.$1.split(/\s+/);
  if(parts.length < 5){
    throw new Error('unexpected result from ps');
  }
  if(!parts[2].match(/^[IRSTU]/)){
    //throw new Error('process is not running: %s',parts[2]);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

if(nodeVersion > 0.1044){ // node versions greater than v0.10.44
  var result=require('child_process').spawnSync('ps',[pid]);
  console.log(util.format('process %s %s running', pid, isProcessRunning(pid,result.stdout.toString()) ? 'is' : 'IS NOT'));
}
else {  // node versions less than or equal to v0.10.44
  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
      ps    = spawn('ps', [pid]);

  ps.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    txt+=data.toString();
  });

  ps.stderr.on('data',function(data){
    console.error('ps error: '+data);
  });

  ps.on('close', function() {
    console.log(util.format('process %s %s running', pid, isProcessRunning(pid,txt) ? 'is' : 'IS NOT'));
  });
}
```

The `isProcessRunning` function takes a `pid` to check and `str` which is the output from running the `ps` command to retrieve the run state of the process, extracts the useful state from the string (using Regular Expressions to find the correct line and field on that line), and returns true or false, depending on the process' reported run state.

It's ***very important*** to note that for versions of Node that are greater than `v0.10.44`, the call to `child_process.spawnSync` is *synchronous* and so, will *block the event loop* from doing anything else until the child process has completed.

This code was tested using Node v4.0.0.

### On Windows

The same approach (shelling out to execute a command to check process status) can be used but instead of `ps`, you'd need to use [the Windows-specific `tasklist` command](https://superuser.com/questions/18830/is-there-a-command-in-windows-like-ps-aux-in-unix) to retrieve information about a specific process.